# How to replicate contents of one variable into another in R?

Tags: r, variables

I'd like to create a new variable with the contents of an existing variable in R...

So far, I've tried:

```
 dataset2018$income2 = 
 dataset2018$income.valueOf();
```

However, I'm getting the following error "Error: attempt to apply non-function"

Grateful for any suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `dataset2018$income2 <- dataset2018$income`

Comment: What are you trying to do with `dataset2018$income.valueOf();`? That doesn't look like common R syntax.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly:

```
cars$new <- cars$speed
```

Or, for your example:

```
 dataset2018$income2 <- dataset2018$income.valueOf
```

The error stems from the empty brackets after the column name, which is only used for functions

Comment: You're right, changed it to an example using the `cars` dataset